# Wix Bundle - How to include EXE and and support files

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I am trying to create a WiX bundle that contains my msi installer along with a thrid-party driver installer.

The third-party installer consists of an executable called *Install_x64.exe* and a few support files (.dll, etc.).  The issue is that *Install_x64.exe* expects a folder in its working directory called *X64* that contains all the support files it needs.

Adding my MSI installer to the chain can be done using `<MsiPackage>` element.  Adding the executable is also straight-forward using `<ExePackage>`.  However, how do I ensure that WiX creates *X64* folder and unpacks the support files there before executing *Install_x64.exe*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the pull name in the "Name" attribute of `<Payload>` element worked.  It creates the desired folder structure.

The example below creates a subfolder names 'X64' and places all the support files there.

```
<ExePackage 
            Id="FintekInstaller"
            SourceFile="..\Drivers\FitSdk\Install_x64.exe">
            <Payload Name="X64\fintek.cat" SourceFile="..\Drivers\FitSdk\X64\fintek.cat"/>
            <Payload Name="X64\Fintek.sys" SourceFile="..\Drivers\FitSdk\X64\Fintek.sys"/>
            <Payload Name="X64\FitSdk.dll" SourceFile="..\Drivers\FitSdk\X64\FitSdk.dll"/>
            <Payload Name="X64\FitSdk.inf" SourceFile="..\Drivers\FitSdk\X64\FitSdk.inf"/>
</ExePackage>
```